# The Art of Electronics 1.35

Tags: voltage-divider, high-pass-filter

Forgive me if this is not the proper question format.  Please critique it if not.  I am new to this site.  I am reading "The Art of Electronics" and cannot understand the jump made in equation 1.35 to go to from \$V_{out} = \frac{R}{[(R^2 + (1/\omega^2C^2))]^{1/2}}V_{in}\$ to 
\$V_{out} = \frac{2\pi fRC}{[1 + (2\pi fRC)^2]^{1/2}}V_{in}\$ for the magnitude of the Voltage output in a generalized voltage divider.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$V_{out}= \frac{R}{{(R^2+(1/\omega^2C^2))}^{1/2}}V_{in}$$

$$V_{out}^2= \frac{R^2}{{R^2+(1/\omega^2C^2)}}V_{in}^2$$

$$V_{out}^2= \frac{R^2\omega^2C^2}{{R^2\omega^2C^2+1}}V_{in}^2$$

$$V_{out}^2= \frac{(R\omega C)^2}{{(R\omega C)^2+1}}V_{in}^2$$

$$V_{out} = \frac{R\omega C}{{((R\omega C)^2+1)^{1/2}}}V_{in}$$

$$V_{out} = \frac{2\pi fRC}{{((2\pi fRC)^2+1)^{1/2}}}V_{in}$$

Comment: The second to fourth equations should read \$V_{out}^2\$ and \$V_{in}^2\$. You don't "square" or "square root" nominator and denominator, you do it to both sides of the equation.

Comment: Yup, I wasnt really paying attention to the non-fraction parts, corrected

Comment: Excellent response, I think this is something many students struggle with... I know I did when I started out with transfer functions.